# Select XML value using id in XSLT

Tags: java, xml, pdf, xslt

I'm trying to transform an XML document using XSLT transformation and was wondering if it is possible to get XML element having value of another attribute.

```
<Question>
<text id="154014">Email</text>
<answer>123@gmail.com</answer>
</Question>

<Question>
<text id="154015">Phone</text>
<answer>123456</answer>
</Question>
```

So my question is that if I have **text/@id** value as **154014** I need to get answer **123@gmail.com**

I can not use `<xsl:value-of select="text[@id='154014']" />` because it will take not needed xml element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it will provide you the desire output:

`//text[@id = '154014']/following-sibling::answer`
OR
`//Question[text[@id = '154014']]/answer`
OR
`//text[@id = '154014']/../answer`

Answer (score 3):

Another way to achieve this, is by means of a [key](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-10/#key). Define a key like so, to look up `Question` elements by the `text/@id`

```
 <xsl:key name="questions" match="Question" use="text/@id" />
```

Then to get the relevant answer of an id, do this...

```
<xsl:value-of select="key('questions', '15184')/answer" />
```

Or, use a parameter instead of a hard-coded value

```
<xsl:value-of select="key('questions', $id)/answer" />
```

See http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/nc4NzRv

Answer (score 0):

Try with this.

```
<xsl:for-each select="Question">
    <xsl:variable name="id" select="text/@id"/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$id='154014'">
            <xsl:value-of select="answer"/>
        </xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:for-each>
```